# Installing a npm package from the nodejs script

Tags: node.js

I need to use a module adm-zip in my nodejs code, but i dont want to install the package first and then use in the code. I want to install the package from my code only.

I have following code with me.

```
// Javascript program to read an integer from STDIN and output it to STDOUT
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var sys = require('util');


var exec = require('child_process').exec; 
    function puts(error, stdout, stderr) 
    { 
        var unzip=require('adm-zip');
        var filename = process.argv[2].split('/').pop()
        var file = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
        var request = http.get(process.argv[2], function(response) {
        response.pipe(file);
        response.on('end',function(){
            var name = process.argv[2].split('/').pop();
            setTimeout(function() {
                    var zip=new unzip(name);
                    process.stdout.write(zip.getEntries().length+"\n");
                }, 500);
        });
    });
    } 
exec("npm install adm-zip", puts);
```

The above works but takes lot of time to run,I wanted to reduce the time taken to run this. Also the adm-zip package needs to be installed from the nodejs code only.Any help?

Comment: Why would you want to install a package from node.js code? Can you elaborate? There might be a better solution than this.

Comment: What is your exact requirement and why would you want to install a package from code? You could do a lot of things from batch file if its some sort of backend process either way

Comment: @Catfish: i was looking forward to automate this actually, like if i want to install a new package i can do it from script, but this script is taking too long  to do that

Comment: What would you be calling this code to automate installing a package? Or how would you be using it? Can you provide a sample use case?